# Calling p/invoke on cross platform (ubuntu/windows) with library that contains dots

Tags: c#, .net-core, cross-platform, pinvoke, dllimport

I am trying to develop a program in C# that builds and runs both in linux (ubuntu 18.04) and Windows, which references a C++ library (via p/invoke - `dllimport`). My dll is imported as a `EmbeddedResource`, but I have also tried `None Include = "..."`

My C++ dll/so contains dots in the naming, and this is giving me a headache.

If I rename my file to have no dots, it works fine. When I add dots, if I do not add the extension (i.e. `.dll` in windows), I get a `DllNotFoundException`, and obviously I do not want to mention the extension name since I want to cross compile it.

Example:

```cs
public const string DllImport = @"myLib110";

[DllImport(DllImport)]
public static extern IntPtr myFun(float[] input);
```

Works fine with `myLib110.dll`

Where:

`public const string DllImport = @"myLib1.1.0";`

Breaks for file `myLib1.1.0.dll`.

In addition:

`public const string DllImport = @"myLib1.1.0.dll";`

Works fine, but I want to cross compile, so that will not work for linux, where my lib is a `.so` file.

Any tips/suggestions ? I also tried most of `DllImport`'s additional input arguments without any luck.

Comment: Which version of .NET are you using? .NET Core/Mono/classic .NET? Mono has dllmaps, .NET Core 3 has APIs for that, look [there](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/master/Documentation/design-docs/dllmap.md)

Comment: At the moment I am targeting `netcoreapp2.1` , so .NET Core. But I have also tried with `net461` unsuccefully .

Comment: Thanks @PavelAnikhouski for the link, I was not aware that microsoft is planning on adding DllMaps with .net core 3. I will try to re configure my code and try it with `netcoreapp3.0`

Comment: It worked @PavelAnikhouski and I have mentioned you in my answer. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following @PavelAnikhouski 's suggestion, I tried targeting `netcoreapp3.0` instead of 2.1 as I was doing previously and incorporated the example found [here](https://github.com/dotnet/samples/tree/master/core/extensions/DllMapDemo) .

It works very smoothly, with one exception (pun not intended):

When running my unit tests, I kept getting a `InvalidOperationException` from the second unit test and onwards for the `NativeLibrary.SetDllImportResolver` method. As microsoft mentions in their [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.nativelibrary.setdllimportresolver?view=netcore-3.0) for the class:

> Only one resolver can be registered per assembly. Trying to register a second resolver fails with an InvalidOperationException.

But I do not understand why would that be the case for my unit tests. The workaround I did was to wrap a `try/catch` inside `public static void Register(Assembly assembly)` (Map.cs). Specifically:

```
try
{
    NativeLibrary.SetDllImportResolver(assembly, MapAndLoad);
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(e);
}
```

Did the trick for me.